# Problemas con autoload en php

Tags: php, mvc, poo

Colegas

tengo la siguiente interrogante, resulta que estoy trabajando con mvc sin framework, y tengo problemas con autoload me da el siguiente error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Model\ProyectoModelo' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Fondos2\index.php:42 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\Fondos2\index.php on line 42

ire directo al grano,

este es el codigo de mi autoload

```
<?php namespace config;
 class Autoload{
public static function run(){
    spl_autoload_register(function($class){
        $ruta = str_replace("\\", "/", $class).".php";
        if(is_readable($ruta)){
            include_once $ruta;
        }
        //print $ruta;
    });
}
}
```

este es el codigo de mi index:

```
  require_once "config/Autoload.php";
   config\Autoload::run();
   new Model\ProyectoModelo();
```

y este es el código de mi modelo

```
<?php namespace Model;
class ProyectoModelo
{
private $IdVicarias;

private $NombreProyecto;

private $SolicitudAporte;

private $AnoProyecto;

private $PersonaResponsable;

private $RbtEntregaCuota;

private $TotalRendiciones;

private $SaldoxRendir;

private $SaldoRendido;

private $porcCuotasRecibidas;

private $con;

public function __Construct()
{
    $this->con = new Conectar();
}
}
```

Si me pudiesen ayudar estaria muy agradecido

Answer (score 1):

Como tenes ordenado los archivos? Quizas no tenes el modelo dentro de la carpeta Model, es un dolor de cabeza y mas cuando tu trabajo se agrande, te recomiendo usar composer, te genera un autolaod mucho mas inteligente que el que estas queriendo usar (Lo usan muchos). Usar composer te ayuda para esto y mucho mas cosas como por ejemplo usar codigo de terceros y adaptarlo a tu proyecto, de los contrario tendras que decargar los archivos manualmente y luego ubicarlos en las carpetas que tu actual autoload esta leyendo, osea un dolor de cabeza, con composer estableces una carpeta donde estaran tus clases y este los llama cuando los necesites y si tenes otras carpetas adentro de este, no se hace problemas, ni vas a tener problemas con los namespaces.

Mi recomendación es esa, como hacerlo?

Requisitos (tener instalado):

1. Composer
2. GitBash

Una vez instalado ambos, haces lo siguiente:

1. Con la consola de Git Bash vas a directorio de tu proyecto
2. Creas un archivo llamado composer.json
3. Con la consola ejecutas el siguiente comando `composer update`

Con esto te creara una carpeta llamada "vendor", en ella se guardaran todos las librerias, trabajos o clases de terceros que luego podras utilizar.

Con esto ya tenes instalado composer pero todavia falta configurar la carpeta donde estan tus clases.

Para eso hacemos lo siguiente:

1. En tu index.php tenes que incluir el autolaod de Composer: `require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';`
2. Abris el archivo que creaste (composer.json) y lo modificas a tu gusto, aca te dejo como lo tengo yo en uno de mis proyectos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dentro de la carpeta llamada "app" tengo todas mis clases, vos podes tenerlo donde quieras siempre y cuando lo aclares en el composer.json

**Plus!**

Si te fijas tenes un campo llamado "files" la cual te dirige a un archivo .php en ese archivo tengo funciones que se pueden ejecutar desde cualquier clase sin tenes que instanciar nada, son funciones sueltas que las puedo llamar desde donde yo quiera.

Una vez que metas tus clases en la carpeta "app" podras instanciarlo desde el index.php con el namespace que estes usando.

**NOTA**
Cada vez que crees una clase nueva tenes que actualizar el autoload y lo haces de la siguiente manera:

Con la consola vas a la raiz de tu proyecto y con la consola de GitBash ejecutas el sigueinte comando: `composer dump-autoload`

Listo!

**Otros datos**

Yo tengo mi carpeta organizada asi:

- App
- --- Controladores
- --- Modelos

Y dentro cada carpeta tnego otras clases, vos lo organizas como quieras, pero tenes que tener una carpeta "madre" por asi decirlo, composer te mapea toda la carpeta con sus respectivos namespaces y listo!

Espero que te sirva como ami, lo que vos estas haciendo me dio varios dolores de cabeza y mas cuando el proyecto se agranda y son mas clases y demas.
Saludos

Comment: Estimado muchas gracias! de verdad,
la estructura de mi carpeta es esta
--Fondo 
  --config
   --Autoload
  --Controller
  --model
  --view
--Index.php

Comment: Si usas composer te salva la vida y encima tiene algunas cosas mas que vale la pena leer, es una maravilla, ja, suerte compañero!

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que el la ruta generada no este considerando la ruta del DirectoryRoot.

usa `dirname(__FILE__)` para considerarla y si esta en una subcarpeta el autoload sal de ella con `'../'`

spl_autoload_register(function($class){
    $class = ltrim($class, '\');
    $ruta = dirname(**FILE**) .'/../'. str_replace("\", DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class).".php";
    if(is_readable($ruta)){
        include_once $ruta;
    }
    //print $ruta;
});